# Why doesn't implicit conversion work with wide ostream?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, iostream, overload-resolution

I have some behaviour that I do not understand. I observed this on VS2005, but [IDEONE (using GCC 4.7.2) outputs](http://ideone.com/doSHvq) basically the same.

Here's the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

struct UserString {
    const char* p;
        operator const char*() const {
                std::cout << "! " << __FUNCTION__ << std::endl;
                return p;
        }

        UserString()
        : p ("UserString")
        { }
};

struct WUserString {
        const wchar_t* p;
        operator const wchar_t*() const {
                std::cout << "! " << __FUNCTION__ << std::endl;
                return p;
        }

        WUserString()
        : p (L"WUserString")
        { }
};


int main() {
        using namespace std;
        cout << "String Literal" << endl;
        cout << string("std::string") << endl;
        cout << UserString() << endl;
        cout << static_cast<const char*>(UserString()) << endl;

        wcout << L"WString Literal" << endl;
        wcout << wstring(L"std::wstring") << endl;
        wcout << WUserString() << endl;
        wcout << static_cast<const wchar_t*>(WUserString()) << endl;

        return 0;
}
```

Here's the output:

```
String Literal
std::string
! operator const char*  **** "works"
UserString              ****
! operator const char*
UserString
WString Literal
std::wstring
! operator const wchar_t*  **** "doesn't" - op<<(void*) is used
0x80491b0                  ****
! operator const wchar_t*
WUserString
```

What's going on here?!?

Comment: Standard iostream lossage.  It doesn't need your converter to accept a pointer value.  You lose because that one is cheaper.

Comment: @HansPassant - Your comment doesn't explain why the behavior is different for `char` vs. `wchar_t`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a partial specialization for basic_ostream

```
template<class _TraitsT>
basic_ostream<char, _TraitsT>&
   operator<<(basic_ostream<char, _TraitsT>& _Stream, const char* _String);
```

which is a good fit for the `cout << UserString()` case.

There is nothing similar for `wchar_t` and `WUserString()`, so the member function

```
basic_ostream& operator<<(const void* _Address);
```

will be the best match for that (as in most "unusual" cases).

Comment: Thanks. That explains it. Do you happen to know or have a pointer as to why this partial specialization exists for `char*`? The asymmetry here is a bit annoying.

Comment: "unusual" is a nice euphemism ;-) ... IMHO, `operator<<(const void* _Address);` is more of a bug than a feature. I think for every case where I have used it, there are 20 cases where it's bitten me at runtime.

Comment: It's just history I guess, but I have no real evidence. There are several other specializations for `char` and `char*` (and even for `signed char` and `unsigned char`) that might have been thought of as chances for some optimizations, possibly.